# What can I do to get Mathematica to solve this equation?

Tags: equation-solving

I am trying to solve an equation on Mathematica 12.1 to get angles in radians as part of some analysis:

```
forceToStrain[in_] := in/(51.76*10^9);
strainFromTheta[in_] := ((in/(2*Sin[in/2])) - 1) // N
(*thickness = 0.28 * 16 ply = 4.48 mm = 4.48*10^(-2 m)*)

Solve[((x/(2*Sin[x/2])) - 1) == forceToStrain[10], x]
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Reduce::inex: Reduce was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients or the system obtained by direct rationalization of inexact numbers present in the system. Since many of the methods used by Reduce require exact input, providing Reduce with an exact version of the system may help.
```

It doesn't seem complicated as an equation as I can solve it by hand:

```
strainFromTheta[.00007]
forceToStrain[10]
Output: 2.04167*10^-10 and 1.93199*10^-10
```

Can anyone tell me whether I could use a different function or rearrange the equation differently to get the angles?

Comment: It is weird that `Solve` does not work. You can get solutions using `FindRoot`, but you will have to specify a "guess" as a starting point. `FindRoot[((x/(2*Sin[x/2])) - 1) == 
  forceToStrain[10], {x, .1}](*{x\[Rule]0.00006809393481894709\`}*)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `Plot[((x/(2*Sin[x/2])) - 1) == forceToStrain[10], {x, -2, 2},  WorkingPrecision -> 35]`suggests possible roots are located near the origin. Making use of it, the following commands work well.

```
forceToStrain[in_] := in/(51.76*10^9);
strainFromTheta[in_] := ((in/(2*Sin[in/2])) - 1) // N

Solve[((x/(2*Sin[x/2])) - 1) == forceToStrain[10] && x >= -0.1 && 
  x <= 0.1, x, WorkingPrecision -> 40]
(*{{x -> -0.000068094}, {x -> 0.000068094}}*)
NSolve[((x/(2*Sin[x/2])) - 1) == forceToStrain[10] && x >= -0.1 && 
  x <= 0.1, x, WorkingPrecision -> 40, Method ->"DifferentialEvolution"]
(*{{x-> -0.00006809395681119561597156442...},{x -> 0.00006809395681119561597156442191...}}*)
FindRoot[((x/(2*Sin[x/2])) - 1) - forceToStrain[10] == 0, {x, 10^-3}, 
 WorkingPrecision -> 30]
(*{x -> 0.0000680939568079706253704515525266}*)
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks. It seems using absolute timing gives Solve (4.18s), NSolve (3.95s), and FindRoot (0.00836s).

Comment: @Zhao: Did you use `ClearAll["Global`*"]` in order to obtain unbiased timings?

Comment: No - fair point. Thanks. Doing that now returns Solve (3.9651s), NSolve (3.8633s), and FindRoot (0.0018s). I shall be using FindRoot in this case.

Comment: @Zhao: It is not so simple. The `FindRoot` command returns only one root  and fails with `{x,0}`. I don't think the execution time is of  very importance here.